# Autofill textbox based on the one textbox value and output it another textbox

Tags: c#, database, winforms, events, textbox

[image: This is the form]
In the load event I managed to set the autocomplete source of `txtITEM`. I am trying to display data from database in txtITEM. but I want to auto fill the remaining `TextBox`es: `txtITEMCODE` , `txtITEMNAME`, `txtPRICE` , `txtSTOCKS` (see the orange arrow) based on the value of `txtITEM`.

How can I do it?

```
private void frmPOS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT  ItemCode,ItemName,Price,Stocks FROM INVENTORY;", con);
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    AutoCompleteStringCollection Collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Collection.Add(rdr.GetString(1));
    }

    txtITEM.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Collection;

    con.Close();

}
```

how to autofill the `txtITEMCODE` , `txtITEMNAME`, `txtPRICE` , `txtSTOCKS` based on the `txtITEM`?

i need this pls , thank you in advance

Comment: thank you for editing this is my first time , SORRY :(

Comment: Don't worry. the edit option is a feature. When you do this with other peoples posts you earn reputation ;) Have a look on my answer, hope it helps you. If you have problems drop me a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options. Either read every time the user selects a certain value the corresponding values from the DB and populate your `TextBox`es.

Or you could read them once and store all the values that you get from the DB somewhere in the code. For the latter I give you a small illustration how it can be done.

```
// store here all your values later
List<string> allvalues = new List<string>();

private void frmPOS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // all your DB stuff...

    // here are my example values
    // NOTE! your values might be separated differently!
    allvalues.Add("ItemCode,ItemName,Price,Stocks");
    allvalues.Add("ItemCode2,ItemName2,Price2,Stocks2");
    allvalues.Add("ItemCode3,ItemName3,Price3,Stocks3");
    allvalues.Add("ItemCode4,ItemName4,Price4,Stocks4");


    AutoCompleteStringCollection Collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    // corresponds to your rdr.GetString(1) command
    Collection.Add("ItemName");
    Collection.Add("ItemName2");
    Collection.Add("ItemName3");
    Collection.Add("ItemName4");

    txtITEMNAME.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Collection;
    txtITEMNAME.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    txtITEMNAME.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;        
}
```

Now you need to decide when exactly you want to populate the rest. I decide in this example to do that when the user has chosen the right autocomplete value and pressed the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. So I use the `KeyDown` event to check for that and populate all the other `TextBoxes`:

```
private void txtITEMNAME_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // separate your values with split according to your separator
        string[] seperatedvalues = allvalues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(txb_ItemAutocomplete.Text)).Split(',');

        if(seperatedvalues.Length == 4) // make sure that you found any values at all
        {
            txb_Code.Text = seperatedvalues[0];
            txb_Price.Text = seperatedvalues[2];
            txb_Stocks.Text = seperatedvalues[3];
        }
    }
}
```

Have fun adjusting this code to your needs. I hope it helps.

Comment: you are welcome, if it helps you to solve your problem you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: when i press enter it doesn't show up in the textboxes in the Item Code , Item , Price , Stocks ?

Comment: its shows up but it show ItemCode text , i would like to display in the textboxes  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qldkrcag8fifz01/Screenshot_6.png?dl=0 , just avoid the description and the category XD

Comment: I don't understand you. you asked "how to autofill the txtITEMCODE ?" and now you say: "but it show ItemCode text" ?=! How did you solve the collection of values from your database?

Comment: like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_eh6QrPAJ4&t=252s start at 4:00 , sorry

Comment: then you need to do this in the `TextChanged` event, instead of `KeyDown`. You would then check and fill at each new character that is typed in the textbox

Comment: the WORDS "Item Code, Price, Stocks" shows in the textbox but not the Item Code, Price, and Stocks of the item. and the Item Name is empty after I've entered the text "camel". that happens before you said to use the "TextChanged". And can you please give me a sample code of the "TextChanged" event and explain it further? thank you sir, have a nice day

Comment: @Pudge Now I understand. You asked how to do the auto fill, I answered this question with an example. I will not write the entire code for you, also because I simply cannot. I don't have access to your database! and I don't know how your values look like. It is up to you to read your data base and get the values. I showed you in my example how to use a collection to store values and how to use the `KeyDown` to search the collection for the corresponding values of the typed keyword. It is up to you to adjust my example so you can make it work with your database code

Comment: @Pudge "the WORDS "Item Code, Price, Stocks" shows in the textbox but not the Item Code ". Of course because they are in the collection `allvalues` you need to put the right values from your database into this collection. The Item Name is empty because I thought you would type in the search value there. Do you understand why and how the values end up in the textboxes?

Comment: Yes sir , Thank you sir , i have solved it by realizing my codes  and realizing yours hahah but anyways thank you so much for your time and effort , i manage to display it . https://www.dropbox.com/s/7afj2cqb5nmbxht/Screenshot_1.png?dl=0

Comment: Glad to hear that you managed it. Sounds like you learned a lot ;) The best way to say thank you on StackOverflow is to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) I wish a good day and fortune in the future